# I'm getting std class vector has no member error for all my vector methods

Tags: c++

My professor sent me the code and most of it works but this part is having problems. All the methods from vector class are showing error. I don't have much experience with c++ but I need to run the code. He was running the same code and it was working just fine.

error is: class "std::vector<int, std::allocator >" has no member "begin"

almost same for all other methods as well

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include "State.h"
#include "SearchNode.h"
#include "Game.h"

vector<int> input() {
    vector<int> input;

    cout << "Input nine different numbers from 0 to 8. " << endl;
    cout << "For instance, put in 7, 0, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2" << endl;

    do {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        if (num < 0 || num > 8
                || std::find(input.**begin()**, input.**end()**, num) != input.**end()**) {
            cout << "Invalid input. Try again." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        input.**push_back(num)**;

        if (input.**size()** < 9)
            cout << "Input " << (9 - input.**size()**) << " more numbers." << endl;
    } while (input.**size()** < 9);

    return input; 
}
```

another part of a header file is also having the same error but it's too long to post here:

```
        State currentState = *initialState;
        std::priority_queue<State> searchQueue;

        std::stack<State> searchedList;

        cout << "Initial state: " << endl;
        currentState.printBoard();
        cout << "Best first search starts ... " << endl;

        searchQueue.push(currentState);

        while (!currentState.isGoalAchieved() && stepsLeft > 0
                && !searchQueue.empty()) {
            std::vector<State> stateList = nextStates(currentState);
            for (int i = 0; i < stateList.**size()**; i++) {
                if (!checkExist(searchedList, stateList[i])) {
                    searchQueue.push(stateList[i]);
                }
            }

            if (!searchQueue.empty()) {
                currentState = searchQueue.top();
                searchQueue.pop();
            }

            cout << endl;
            currentState.printBoard();
            searchedList.push(currentState);

            cout << "Number of states visited up to now " << searchedList.size()
                    << ". " << endl;

            stepsLeft--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you add `#include <vector>`?

Comment: `vec..**size()**` is invalid syntax.

Comment: The rule of thumb: if you use a `std::vector` in your file, make sure to `#include <vector>` **in that exact file**. Don't rely that other included files include it for you as well

Comment: @JatinderBrar So the next point is does your code really say `input.**push_back(num)**;` or is that you trying to highlight the places where the errors occur. You should also post the exact error message you are getting (just the first one should be enough).

Comment: @john I was trying to make the errors bold but that didn't work. And the error is: class "std::vector<int, std::allocator <int>>" has no member "begin"

Comment: @JatinderBrar Hmm, that's a strange one.

Comment: @john yeah, he literally copied the source files he was using and sent them to me. Only difference is that he was using different IDE on mac and I'm on visual studio on windows.

Comment: @JatinderBrar Your first code compiles perfectly fine for me if I remove the header files (state.h etc).

Comment: @JatinderBrar Visual Studio has a sneaky trick, it shows error messages out of order. Make sure you are looking at the Output tab, not the Error List tab, and report the first error there. I suspect that something else is going wrong and you're getting confused by the out of order error reporting of Visual Studio.

Comment: @john 1> This is the first and only error in the output tab
C:\...\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

I think there is a problem with my installation but I'm still not sure why it would highlight vector methods.

Comment: @JatinderBrar this might help [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958134/error-c1083-yvalsh-unable-to-include-crtdbgh.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958134/error-c1083-yvalsh-unable-to-include-crtdbgh.html)

Comment: OK, the errors you are seeing are Intellisense errors, they are not the compiler talking. Intellisense is a technology designed to help you write C++ code quicker but it is not a C++ compiler. So those errors can be ignored. Your real compiler error does indeed show that your installation has problems.

Comment: @john and sebastian, That worked!! Thanks for the help, appreciate it. And it seems like a weird design choice, the errors from vector were not letting me compile and run, and I couldn't see the actual error without compiling. I had to look up the shortcut for running the program.

Comment: @JatinderBrar Personally I turn Intellisense off (but some people find it useful) but the Error List tab with its error prone attempts to prioritise errors it just stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing windows sdk. Installing them worked.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958134/error-c1083-yvalsh-unable-to-include-crtdbgh.html